# Constants as parameter in NamedQueries is it a good practice?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using constants to organize my `@NamedQueries`, but I'm in doubt about the parameters, is it a good practice use constants as parameters too?

For example, in the whole application my NamedQueries filter by a company Id. So I created:

```
public static final String PARAM_EMPRESA_ID = "empresaId";
```

And I use like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = EmbalagemAbaSuperiorTipo.QUERY_FETCH_BY_EMPRESA,
            query = "SELECT ep FROM EmbalagemAbaSuperiorTipo ep WHERE ep.empresa.id = :" + AppController.PARAM_EMPRESA_ID + " ORDER BY ep.descricao")
```

Could this cause any performance issue when Hibernate needs to compile the queries? And is there any better recommendation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a Hibernate point of view, `@NamedQuery` annotations are parsed at the startup of Hibernate.  So you shouldn't see any runtime performance concerns.  Its also a nice approach to minimize developer error because you're using compile-time constants rather than strings, which I've used and found useful in my past experiences.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. Well that's the idea minimize developer error and keep a pattern, because in my example after a while developers started to create "empId", "empresaId", "eId" in different places.